# React hook with fetch api

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, react-hooks

I want to make a very simple Fetch request (or axios request) and then map these results.

For that, I'm using useState and useEffect, but I'm definitively doing something wrong.

```
 function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState({});

  const getTodos = () => {
    const urlTodos = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
    return fetch(urlTodos)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
       return res 
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos().then(setTodos);
  }, []);

  const [todosSimple, setTodosSimple] = ([
    {
      text: 'learn about react',
      isCompleted :true
    },
    {
      text: 'Danse',
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ])

  console.log(todosSimple)


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todosSimple.map((todo,index) => {
        return todo;     
      }  
      )}

    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4x9647869)

Comment: I think you are on the right path with the exception of the recommendation already given. Further to that I will point out that optionally you can use async await over the .then chaining. You will need to ensure however that the async does not leak to the useEffect function param as it will complain about the return of a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all you need to change this line

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({});
```

to

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```

Since `todos` variable is going to have a default value, and it's going to be an empty object. And there is no `.map` method on objects, and well you receive an array from the api.

Secondly I would recommend using `setTodos` function inside the `getTodos` in the last then.

```
.then(res => setTodos(res))
```

and then you can map your `todos` in the return

[here's and example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn9l9mwopx?fontsize=14)